# Are the voice and background tracks merged together when filming hollwood movies?

Tags: audio-recording, dvd, mixing

When we watch a movie we can hear background music and voices of actors. We also hear sound effects. When we watch a DVD movie the voice and background music merged inside a language track such as *English language audio track*. Audacity is program used to mix voice-overs and music. It is hard to create an audio track in another language if there is not a separate *sound track*. It is easy to dub a movie when there is a *sound track*.

1. When creating Hollywood movies, are there separate vocal track and a music track?
2. Is there a separate track for sound effects?
3. How do you mix voice and music tracks and convert it into a language track?
4. What is the software used to mix the tracks in question 3?
5. What is an *original sound track (OST)*?
6. Is the *original sound track (OST)* used when dubbing a movie?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We encourage one focused question per post. It would be better if you asked three or more separate questions, maybe 1&2, 3&4 and 5&6, which seem to be related topics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer only the first part, film sound is often split into three parts: music, effects, and dialog. This allows dialog to be replaced for dubbing. This isn't a hard-and-fast rule but it's the general way it's been done for a long time.

This is not how the sound is released, though. For release these are combined into a theatrical mix of two or more (for surround) channels, so the original three-track mix is no longer in play.